# vb.net my project folder vs c# properties folder

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, properties

I am migrating a `C# WinForm` Application to `VB.Net`.

In C# Project I have a `Properties` Folder that is created by default. Inside of it I have defined a Resources file.

In VB.Net appears `My Project`Folder by Default instead.

I have to migrate Resources file from C# to VB.Net... I want to know if I have to create a `Properties` folder or I can use `My Project` Folder instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the VB 'My Project' folder.  This is where VB will expect to find these types of files.  If you're converting the .csproj file manually, remember to change its 'Properties' folder references to 'My Project'.